# Persistent upsert does not compile

Tags: haskell, haskell-persistent

I'm trying to do something in Persistent with PostgreSQL that seems like it should be simple: Given a list of `Attendance` records, overwrite any existing rows with same unique key or insert if they don't exist. Here are the types:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkDeleteCascade sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAllEvents"] [persistLowerCase|
Event json sql=events
    description Text
    date UTCTime
    UniqueEvent date
Attendance json
    attending Bool
    eventId EventId
    user UserId
    UniqueAttendance eventId user
|]
```

I don't have keys, so I can't use `repsert`, but I think `upsert` is what I need. The [documentation for `upsert`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.7.3/docs/Database-Persist-Class.html#v:upsert) looks a bit vague to me: If the record exists and I leave the updates blank, I understand that it will retain the entity as it was. But that's not equivalent to the behavior of `repsert`, as claimed, is it? It also doesn't say what happens when no uniqueness constraint exists.

What I tried was

```
runDb (mapM_ ups atts)
 where 
  -- ups rec = upsert rec [AttendanceAttending =. True] also doesn't work
  ups rec = upsert rec [AttendanceAttending =. (attendanceAttending rec)]
```

but this leads to an error that I don't really understand:

```
• Illegal equational constraint BaseBackend backend ~ SqlBackend
  (Use GADTs or TypeFamilies to permit this)
• When checking the inferred type
    ups :: forall (m :: * -> *) backend.
           (BaseBackend backend ~ SqlBackend, PersistUniqueWrite backend,
            MonadIO m) =>
           Attendance -> ReaderT backend m (Entity Attendance)
```

Any idea what causes this error? `upsertBy` is also the same. I have imported Esqueleto in that same file, but `hiding ((=.))`, so it should be pure Persistent.

Comment: So have you tried to do what the compiler suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarassingly, it really was as simple as adding `{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies      #-}`. I hadn't tried that because I misread the error message and none of my other modules needed that extension. Thanks, Fyodor!